# Cross compile Libzdb library for ARM9 architecture

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am using AM1808 ARM9 based micro processor for my project on ubuntu v10.04 using G++ compiler.

I am using sqlite3 database for data management.

My application needs to multiple access to database simultaneously.

I found i need to implement connection pooling method for efficient working.

I googled little bit and found that Libzdb library is available for connection pool and it is open source.

I dont know how to cross compile this library for ARM9 architecture.

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: assumed you a cross_compile tools chain
Download source code of libzdb.

Step 1: unzip the source code

Step 2: `./configure --help`

here you find two option --host and --build

use `--host=(CROSS_COMPILE_TOOLs)` e.g `--host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi`
this will set to compile code for arm arch.

```
$~ ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=(path-to install)

$~ make

$~make install
```

binaries will be installed to your `--prefix` path